# WxPython Exit Code 139 with Form Window

Tags: python, user-interface, wxpython, exit-code

So this is a pretty basic program but for some reason it keeps crashing wtih exit code 139. I've looked online at the error code and it has to do with memory management but a basic form with a few plaintext, buttons, and fields should  not be too much for a 64 bit machine with 16GB of RAM. I have another class that is almost identical and it works fine. Where am I going wrong here?

```
import wx

class mainForm(wx.Frame):

    def __init__(self):
        wx.Frame.__init__(self, None, title="Test")
        self.panel = wx.Panel(self)

        vbox_main = wx.BoxSizer(wx.VERTICAL)  # main vertical box

        url_box = wx.BoxSizer(wx.HORIZONTAL)
        url_label = wx.StaticText(self.panel, label="URL:")
        self.url_entry = wx.TextCtrl(self.panel)

        url_box.Add(url_box)
        url_box.Add(url_label)
        url_box.Add(self.url_entry)

        file_box = wx.BoxSizer(wx.HORIZONTAL)
        file_label = wx.StaticText(self.panel, label="File")
        self.file_entry = wx.TextCtrl(self.panel)
        file_button = wx.Button(self.panel, label="Search")
        file_button.Bind(wx.EVT_BUTTON, self.search)

        file_box.Add(file_label)
        file_box.Add(self.file_entry)
        file_box.Add(file_button)

        mode_box=wx.BoxSizer(wx.HORIZONTAL)
        mode_label=wx.StaticText(self.panel, label='Mode')
        #self.mode_button = buttons.GenToggleButton(self.panel, -1, "Autonomous Mode")

        mode_box.Add(mode_label)
        #mode_box.Add(self.mode_button)

        go_box = wx.BoxSizer(wx.HORIZONTAL)
        go_button = wx.Button(self.panel, label='Go!')
        go_button.Bind(wx.EVT_BUTTON, self.submit)
        go_box.Add(go_button)

        vbox_main.Add(url_box)
        vbox_main.Add(file_box)
        vbox_main.Add(mode_box)
        vbox_main.Add(go_box)

        self.panel.SetSizer(vbox_main)
        self.Show(True)

    def search(self):
        pass

    def submit(self):
        pass
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can not add wxBoxSizer himself and you need to comment the line:

```
url_box.Add(url_box)
```

Comment: I think the lesson to learn here is never to program tired. Thanks!